# RequireJS, jquery still undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs, undefined

I know this has already been discussed, but after searching for a while I can't figure out why my small setup does not load jquery correctly with requireJS.

I'm running a small sample html page from 'file://' and try to load 2 modules with a call to require:

- jquery
- a custom module I wrote

If my custom module loads correctly (i can use it with its alias in the require call, jquery is always undefined)

I tried to setup paths in require.config, as well as shim (exporting '$' or 'jQuery') but it does not work.

The only way i can get jquery to correctly load, is removing all paths definition and naming the jquery file on my filesystem 'jquery.js'

Here is my config:

**main.js:**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-2.1.3.min' //does not work
        //jquery: 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js' //does not work either
    }
});

console.log( "main.js is loaded" );  //this is correctly ouputed to the console
```

**test.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--
       ... page content ...
    -->

    <!-- main.js is loaded from data-main -->
    <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      require(
          ['jquery','custom'],
          function($, Custom){
            console.info('$:');
            console.info($); //outputs undefined

            console.info('Custom:');
            console.info(Custom); //outputs my custom object        

          });
    </script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Once again, it works if I remove all paths definition for jquery, and simply name my jquery js file 'jquery.js' but this is sloppy.

Can somebody points me on the right way to go ?

Comment: Please add to your question the `script` element that loads RequireJS and how you load your `main` module.

Comment: @Louis: I just added the necessary html code, you can see I call requireJs on body end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you load your RequireJS configuration, which is in `main`, through `data-main`. The `data-main` attribute merely tells RequireJS to load the module listed there but the loading is still *asynchronous*, so `main` may load *after* RequireJS tries to load jQuery. When this happens, RequireJS fails to find jQuery and `$` is undefined. (Incidentally, I'd suggest setting `enforceDefine` to `true` in your RequireJS configuration so that you get an error message telling you when a module has not loaded. That's a better clue than having an undefined symbol.)

One solution would be to move your configuration outside of `main`. So you remove it from `main` and add it to a `script` element in front of the one loading RequireJS:

```
<script>
// RequireJS will use the value of `require` as its configuration.
require = {
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-2.1.3.min'
    },
    enforceDefine: true
};
</script>
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Or you can nest `require` calls to force `main` to load before any other module:

```
require(['main'], function () {
    require(['jquery','custom'], ...
});
```

Comment: You got it! It was asynchronous issue between jquery and main load.

Comment: The only way I had it solved was to nest jquery and custom require in main require.
Just a quick question: By adding enforeDefine it made the jquery require fails although when I remove it, jquery is correctly loaded as a module and available in my '$' variable.

Comment: I forgot that the module loaded by `data-main` is *not exempt* from the `define` requirement if `enforceDefine` is turned on. So I've edited my answer to remove `data-main` if you follow the first option. (`data-main` should be pointless anyway, once you have moved the call to `require.config` out of it). This is the only issue I can think of. (See the **NOTE** in [this section](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#ieloadfail). The note applies to all browsers, not just IE.)